# xp_readerrorlog "Invalid parameter type" with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to write some code to query the SQL Error Log from a SQL 2008R2 instance.  Here's what I have:

```
declare @Start_Time  DATETIME = NULL;
declare @End_Time    DATETIME = NULL;

IF @Start_Time IS NULL 
  SELECT @Start_Time = GETDATE()-1
IF @End_Time   IS NULL 
  SELECT @End_Time   = GETDATE()

select @start_time start_time, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@start_time,120) conv_s_time
select @End_time   end_time,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@End_time,120)   conv_e_time
EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0, 1, '', '', '2015-09-17 11:47:16', '2015-09-18 11:47:16' 
EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0, 1, '', '', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@Start_Time,120) ' 
EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0, 1, '', '', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@Start_Time,120) ' , ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@End_Time,120) '
```

The output of this is:

```
start_time  conv_s_time
2015-09-17 11:59:10.617 2015-09-17 11:59:10

end_time    conv_e_time
2015-09-18 09:35:10.617 2015-09-18 09:35:10

LogDate ProcessInfo Text
<  2000+ rows of data >

LogDate ProcessInfo Text
<  45,000+ rows of data >

Msg 22004, Level 12, State 1, Line 0
Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter Type
```

The call to xp_ReadErrorLog works with two hardcoded dates (start and end) and with one variable as the start date but fails when both start and end dates are specified as variables.  Does anyone have any suggestion on why I can't use variables for both parameters in the call to xp_ReadErrorLog?

Any help appreciated.

Ken

Comment: Is there a reason to convert the parameters to varchar? Using variables directly worked for me.

Comment: I'm modifying code from another developer and don't know why they did the call to CONVERT within the parameters.  You are correct, passing in just the start_time and end_time parameters works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

---------------- SQL Script -----------------------------

```
Declare @Today varchar(50)
declare @tomorrow varchar(50)
declare @Statement nvarchar(100)

set @today = (select convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112))
Print @Today
set @Tomorrow= (select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 112))
Print @tomorrow

Set @Statement = 'EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0,2, N''error'', N''Failed'', '+'N'''++@tomorrow+''''++','+ ++'N'''+@today+''''
Print @Statement 
exec sp_executesql @Statement
```

----------------- Result ---------------------------

[image: Result sample]